# getting Restricted operation on a server while getting AdministrationProcess from Session in IBM Domino

Tags: java, lotus-domino

I have a requirement to add group members to an IBM Domino Group through java code. I am using Notes.jar to connect to IBM Domino v9.0, and my java code is running on a different machine, then the Domino machine.
From the Domino documentation I found out that "AdministrationProcess" class needs to be used to add member to group. But when i am trying to create "AdministrationProcess" object by calling session.createAdministrationProcess("IBMDominoServer"). I am getting the error **Restricted operation on a server**.

My test code is as follows

```
public class LotusDomino{
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{
    String[] argv = {"192.168.2.111","Administrator","<password>"};
    deleteUser(argv[0], argv[1], argv[2]);
}
private static void deleteUser(String host, String userName, String password) throws Exception{
    Session s = NotesFactory.createSession(host, userName, password);
    try{
        AdministrationProcess process = s.createAdministrationProcess("IBMDominoServer.xanadufinancials.com");
    }catch(NotesException e){
        System.err.println("exception --- "+e.id+":"+e.text+":"+e.internal); // this prints the following error : exception --- 4183:Restricted operation on a server:null
    }
}
```

The code shows same error irrespective of what i pass in as the *server Name* . So it shouldn't be a code issue. I did a little bit of search for this, and found out that Administrator should have editor access on admin4.nsf. Verified the access it was present.

Please let me know what can be the issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure you're using Notes.jar?  The above looks and sounds more like you're using NCSO.jar.

Comment: yeah i am using Notes.jar

Answer (score 2):

Using the Administration Process is one way to add a user to a group, and it is the safest way when you have no knowledge of how directory services on the Domino server have been configured.  But in most basic configurations, adding a user to a group is very simple. You open the names.nsf database, open the Groups view, locate the document for the group, and add the name to the list stored in the Members item.  The one catch is that if the Members list is too long, you may have to write code that is capable of divide it into subgroups (and/or code to detect the pattern of existing subgroups and add to them instead).

Regarding using the NotesAdministrationProcess class, if we can trust that the error message means what it says it means, then your problem is that the user id you are using does not have permission to run restricted operations on the server.  Here is a [link to info about server configuration](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_SETTING_UP_AGENT_SECURITY_USING_THE_SECURITY_TAB_OVER.html) for agent permissions.  If you're using NCSO.jar (see my question above), then  be a separate configuration for users permitted to perform restricted operations over IIOP, but I'm not sure and my server is down at the moment so I can't check.

Comment: Okay... my server's back up and I checked.  ""Run unrestricted methods and operations" field in the Programmability section of the Security tab of the Server Document in the Domino Directory covers all languages and interfaces, including IIOP.  (Pay no attention to the fac that it says "Unrestricted" and you need  permission for "Restricted".  The help text makes clear that what this field really does is specify who can run code without restrictions. I.e., run restricted operations. They just describe it backwards in the field label.)

Comment: Thanks Richard, I was able to get this working by changing. I couldn't find the setting you mentioned, but modifying the setting "Sign or run unrestricted methods and operations works" did the magic